# SQL Join after Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the distinct values in A based in condition from column B.

The problem is that if I all, the conditions wont be respected.

If I distinct only the value I want, column B data is not joined.

What have I tried:

Query A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_conversacion, convo_started, started_by, has_unread, pr_token,
                hidden_started, hidden_recipiente, de_persona, para_persona, convo_perteneciente
FROM cs_conversaciones
INNER JOIN cs_privatemessages
    ON cs_privatemessages.convo_perteneciente = cs_conversaciones.id_conversacion
WHERE cs_privatemessages.de_persona = 123456 OR
      cs_privatemessages.para_persona = 123456
ORDER BY id_conversacion
```

Output (Didnt type all columns outputed, just an example):

```
|id_conversacion|convo_started|started_by|has_unread|pr_token|...etc|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|1              |  2016-06-05 |  123456  |     0    |  dd5f4 | 
|1              |  2016-06-05 |  123456  |     0    |  4fd85 |
|2              |  2016-06-05 |  123456  |     0    |  8sa8s |
```

The outputed columns are ok, but the distinct (id_conversacion), which should relate to `cs_privatemessages.convo_perteneciente`
repeats (1, 1 , 2)

Query B:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_conversacion
FROM cs_conversaciones
INNER JOIN cs_privatemessages
    ON cs_privatemessages.convo_perteneciente = cs_conversaciones.id_conversacion
WHERE cs_privatemessages.de_persona = 123456 OR
      cs_privatemessages.para_persona= 123456
ORDER BY id_conversacion
```

Output:

I get the opposite, the distinct is ok but the outputted columns are not.

```
|id_conversacion|
-----------------
|      1        |
|      2        |
```

Expected Result (missing columns from join):

```
|id_conversacion|convo_started|started_by|has_unread|pr_token|de_persona|etc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1              |  2016-06-05 |  123456  |     0    |  dd5f4 | 123456 |
|2              |  2016-06-05 |  123456  |     0    |  8sa8s | 126544 |
```

Which makes me thing the distinct repeats because there's more 1 row in the join table.

Comment: What is the logic which led you to discard one of the `id_conversacion = 1` records from your result set?

Comment: `distinct` operates on the entire row, not a single column and since the value in the `pr_token` column changes you get more rows. If you only want one row per `id_conversacion` you have to decide which pr_token value you want (possibly by applying min/max and grouping)

Comment: DISTINCT applies to the whole selected rows. If you want each id_conversacion only once, you have to decide which values to chose for the other columns.

Comment: @jpw, it took me 13 seconds to write my comment, very similar to yours.

Comment: If you notice, there are different `pr_token` value for `Id_conversacion = 1`, if you need single row for `Id_conversacion = 1`, then either take `Max(pr_token)` or `Min(pr_token)`.

Comment: max and group by made it. Thanks @jpw

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you trying to do is grouping
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

```
SELECT id_conversacion, convo_started, started_by, has_unread, pr_token,
                hidden_started, hidden_recipiente, de_persona, para_persona, convo_perteneciente
FROM cs_conversaciones
INNER JOIN cs_privatemessages
    ON cs_privatemessages.convo_perteneciente = cs_conversaciones.id_conversacion
WHERE cs_privatemessages.de_persona = 123456 OR
      cs_privatemessages.para_persona = 123456
GROUP BY id_conversacion
ORDER BY id_conversacion
```

But you should use aggregation functions on other columns, or in other case there will be the first row result

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The join table was returning repeated values:

Adding a MAX() and group by solved the issue.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_conversacion, convo_started, started_by, has_unread, MAX(pr_token) as pr_token, hidden_started, hidden_recipiente, MAX(de_persona), MAX(para_persona), convo_perteneciente FROM cs_conversaciones INNER JOIN cs_privatemessages ON cs_privatemessages.convo_perteneciente = cs_conversaciones.id_conversacion WHERE cs_privatemessages.de_persona = 123456 OR cs_privatemessages.para_persona = 123456 GROUP BY id_conversacion,pr_token
```